# Reflection problems with simple ray tracer in GLSL

Tags: glsl, raytracing

I'm writing a simple ray tracer in GLSL 4.0 and I'm having some trouble doing basic reflection with correct shading (phong). I'm writing in a render-to-texture shader (screen aligned quad) My scene consists of 6 spheres and a plane as described in the code below. I use an `Intersection` struct to keep track of intersections and a `Ray` struct for the light ray. As GLSL 4.0 doesn't permit recursion, I am iteratively casting secondary rays (by changing the direction and origin of each the ray every iteration).

```
#version 400

in vec3 dir;
out vec4 outcolour;

uniform mat4 mMatrix;
uniform mat4 mvMatrix;
uniform mat4 mvMatrixScene;
uniform mat4 pMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix; //mv matrix without translation

uniform vec3 light = vec3(6,4,3);
uniform vec4 ambient = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
uniform vec4 diffuse = vec4(1.0,0.1,0.0,1.0);
uniform vec4 specular = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
uniform float ambientCoefficent = 1.0;
uniform float diffuseCoefficent = 1.0;
uniform float specularCoefficent = 1.0;

const float PI = 3.14159265358979;
const int raytraceDepth = 2;
const int numSpheres = 6;

//example data structures
struct Ray
{
    vec3 origin;
    vec3 dir;
};

struct Sphere
{
    vec3 centre;
    float radius;
    vec3 colour;
};

struct Plane
{
    vec3 point;
    vec3 normal;
    vec3 colour;
};

struct Intersection
{
    float t; //closest hit
    vec3 point; // hit point
    vec3 normal; // normal
    int hit; //did it hit?
    vec3 colour; // colour accumulation, can be also implemented in struct Ray
};

void sphere_intersect(Sphere sph, Ray ray, inout Intersection intersect) {
    vec3 dp = ray.origin - sph.centre;
    vec3 d = ray.dir;
    float r = sph.radius;

    // Does the sphere intersect?
    float x = pow(dot(d,dp),2.0) - pow(length(dp),2.0) + pow(r,2.0);
    intersect.hit = 0;

    if (x >= 0) {
        float u1 = dot(-d,dp) + sqrt(x);
        float u2 = dot(-d,dp) - sqrt(x);
        float u = min(u1,u2);
        if (u < intersect.t) {
            intersect.t = u;
            intersect.colour = sph.colour;
            intersect.point = ray.origin + intersect.t*d;
            intersect.hit = 1;
            intersect.normal = (intersect.point - sph.centre) / sph.radius;
        }
    }
}

void plane_intersect(Plane pl, Ray ray, inout Intersection intersect)
{
    float x = dot(ray.dir,pl.normal);
    // Assuming no paralel rays otherwise divide by 0 error
    float h = dot(pl.point - ray.origin,pl.normal)/x;
    intersect.hit = 0;
    //intersect.colour = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    intersect.point = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    if (h >=0 ) {
    float u = -dot((ray.origin - pl.point),pl.normal)/x;
        if (u < intersect.t) {
        intersect.t = u;
        intersect.point = ray.origin + u*ray.dir;
        intersect.normal = pl.normal;
        intersect.hit = 1;

        // Normal used is y so used x and z for checkerboard pattern
            if (int((floor(intersect.point.x) + floor(intersect.point.z)))%2 == 1) {
                intersect.colour = pl.colour;
            } else {
                intersect.colour = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
            }
        }
    }
}

Sphere sphere[numSpheres];
Plane plane;

vec4 local_shading_term(vec3 light, Intersection intersection) {
    float q = 10;
    float d = length(light - intersection.point);
    float s = 10;

    vec3 n = normalize(intersection.normal);
    vec3 l = normalize(light - intersection.point);
    vec3 r = normalize(-reflect(l,n));
    vec3 v = -normalize(intersection.point);
    vec4 diff = diffuse * diffuseCoefficent * vec4(max(dot(n,l),0));
    vec4 spec = specular * specularCoefficent * vec4(pow(max(dot(v,r),0), q));
    return (diff + spec) * 250 / (4 * PI * (d + s));
}

void Intersect(Ray ray, inout Intersection intersection)
{
    vec3 colour = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    int sphere_hits = 0;

    // Sphere intersection
    for (int i=0; i<numSpheres; i++) {
        sphere_intersect(sphere[i],ray,intersection);
        sphere_hits += intersection.hit;
    }

    if (sphere_hits > 0) {
    colour = intersection.colour + vec3(local_shading_term(light,intersection));
    }

    // Plane intersection
    plane_intersect(plane,ray,intersection);

    if (sphere_hits == 0 ) {
        colour = intersection.colour;
    }
    intersection.colour = colour;
}

void main()
{
    //White
    sphere[0].centre = vec3(-2.0, 1.5, -3.5);
    sphere[0].radius = 1.5;
    sphere[0].colour = vec3(0.8,0.8,0.8);

    //Green
    sphere[1].centre = vec3(-0.5, 0.0, -2.0);
    sphere[1].radius = 0.6;
    sphere[1].colour = vec3(0.3,0.8,0.3);

    //Blue
    sphere[2].centre = vec3(1.0, 0.7, -2.2);
    sphere[2].radius = 0.8;
    sphere[2].colour = vec3(0.3,0.8,0.8);

    //Yellow
    sphere[3].centre = vec3(0.7, -0.3, -1.2);
    sphere[3].radius = 0.2;
    sphere[3].colour = vec3(0.8,0.8,0.3);

    //Red
    sphere[4].centre = vec3(-0.7, -0.3, -1.2);
    sphere[4].radius = 0.2;
    sphere[4].colour = vec3(0.8,0.3,0.3);

    //Purple
    sphere[5].centre = vec3(0.2, -0.2, -1.2);
    sphere[5].radius = 0.3;
    sphere[5].colour = vec3(0.8,0.3,0.8);

    plane.point = vec3(0,-0.5, 0);
    plane.normal = vec3(0, 1.0, 0);
    plane.colour = vec3(1, 1, 1);

    vec4 colour = vec4(0,0,0,1);

    Ray ray;
    ray.origin = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    ray.dir = normalize(dir);

    Intersection intersection;
    for (int i=0; i<raytraceDepth; i++) {
        intersection.t = 999999999;
        Intersect(ray,intersection);
        ray.origin = intersection.point;
        ray.dir = reflect(ray.dir,intersection.normal);
    }
    colour = vec4(intersection.colour,0.0);
    outcolour = colour;
}
```

I've debugged my code for a few days but I cannot seem to achieve my target which is best described by the image below:

[image]

Excluding the shadows and precision problems aside, I am trying to achieve the above but right now it looks like this:

[image]

raytraceDepth = 1

[image]
raytraceDepth = 2

As you see, there is random garbage in the background above the plane (probably caused by me not correctly setting the colour value so it uses whatever is in the GPU memory). Sometimes the noise is there when I load the shader, sometimes it's not, it just happened to be there when I took these screenshots. The spheres produce a strange mirror effect when `intersection.point` in `plane_intersect` is set to `vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0)`. If I remove it, I don't see the effect anymore but the actual spheres inside the bigger spheres which is why I kept it.

The idea is that, I intersect a ray with all the objects in the scene. The intersection struct is passed as an `inout` parameter to the function `Intersect()` which tests for intersections with the ray. It fills out the struct with values of the closest visible intersection. So `t` represents the value which is used to determine the point on a ray for which an intersection occured i.e `ray = ray_origin + t*ray_direction`.

I am unsure about why I can't get the correct reflection effect. Can anyone see any problems with my code?

Comment: What algorithm for sphere intersection do You use? I'm a bit confused with what I see in Your code.